# Disable OpenGL for Python / Matplotlib

Tags: linux, opengl, python-3.x, matplotlib, virtualbox

I'm doing a Python course for which I have installed Arch Linux in a VM. When I use Matplotlib.pyplot to plot things (x vs y) I get a bunch of errors.

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 12: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 00007f6ff33d0240
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 00007f6ff33d0240, failed to get XVisualInfo
```

When I turn of 3D support for the VM it simply asks for openGL. My script does create a plot (empty canvas) but without a line.

I think it should be possible to draw some lines without openGL, right? How to go about this...

Edit: I think it was a VirtualBox bug combined with an error in my Python code. I could actually get good graphs with the error messages present in the end. In the latest versions of VirtualBox I'm not getting the error anymore. Thanx for the suggestions.

Comment: mpl does not (directly) touch openpl.  Are you also using `vispy`?  My guess is that this is more generic and related to what ever you gui toolkit is doing, not specific to mpl.

Comment: and your VM is having hardware issues talking to your video card.

Comment: I use

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I think it has to do with the fact that Virtualbox does not support opengl 3. But I keep thinking, I should be able to, in python, not use hw accelaration at all.

Comment: Does it work with the `Agg` backend (`matplotlib.use ('Agg')`)?

Comment: I think it was a virtualbox bug in the end. I'm nut seeing the error anymore, also I found an error in my own Python code, I could actually get good output despite of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, despite of all the errors, I never had anything not working actually, the fact that I didn't see graphs was not due to the error in the original post. It was something else, I guess unrelated tot mpl and more related to lack of 3D acceleration in VirtualBox.